# How to optimize UIImageView

Tags: ios, ipad, caching, optimization, uiimageview

This is my program:
I have cache variable `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *cache;`, where I store my UIImageViews. Images size is 768 × 1024 .

```
UIImageView *cap_1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face1_cap_0.png"]];
    [self.cache setObject:cap_1 
                         forKey:@"cap_1"];
    [cap_1 release];

    UIImageView *cap_2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face1_cap_1.png"]];
    [self.cache setObject:cap_2 
                         forKey:@"cap_2"];
    [cap_2 release];

    UIImageView *cap_3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face1_cap_2.png"]];
    [self.cache setObject:cap_3 
                         forKey:@"cap_3"];
    [cap_3 release];

    UIImageView *cap_4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face1_cap_3.png"]];
    [self.cache setObject:cap_4 
                         forKey:@"cap_4"];
    [cap_4 release];

    UIImageView *cap_5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face1_cap_4.png"]];
    [self.cache setObject:cap_5 
                         forKey:@"cap_5"];
    [cap_5 release];

    UIImageView *cap_6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"face1_cap_5.png"]];
    [self.cache setObject:cap_6 
                         forKey:@"cap_6"];
    [cap_6 release];
```

I use UIImageViews in PanGesture, every 50 pt of swipe I add each UIImageView on my main view. I have lagging only in first time then I add all UIImageViews on main view, but for all another times it works fast. How can I optimize first swipe?  Or please advise me another way do to it.

Comment: when do you initialize your UIImageViews ? Are they set to another superview before swipe ?

Comment: No they not, i only store they in NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You should offload lengthy operations to a different thread so as not to block the UI.
Check [this article](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/08/12/gcd-example-updated-now-with-more-speed/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load it when the app starts so the user doesn't realize when he swipes the first time but in this case the whole app will take longer to open.

Comment: Do all the allocation in your code at the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method. But as I mentioned before it will slow the loading time of the view that contains it. As someone mentions in another answer you could also do this in a different thread so the loading time wouldn't increase as much.

Answer (score 0):

In view did load, you can directly add the images to your main view with hidden property set to YES. Then you just set their property to NO on user swipe.

**EDIT :**

Another solution is to make some thumnails for displaying, keeping your original images for eventually further image computing.

Comment: Thx, do you know another ways?

Comment: The problem does not comes from loading images because you're caching them and imageNamed method also has a cache system. So I think the lag comes from the addSubView method. But I don't think that threading it from the UI is a good idea because it's about UI rendering. 1024x768 is too large for iphone screen. if your resize your images, you should create and display some thumbnails, keeping your original images for working on.

Comment: Ops, it's not iPhone it's for iPad.